# combine css animation with transform

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

Is it possible to comine css transform with some animation?

I have this tarnsform

```
transform: translate(-10%, 0px); left: 0px;
```

which works fine to animate slider left, right scrolling

but I would like to add some **fade in animation** from **opacity 0 to 1**

Comment: I will try to setup a small codepen example, what I try: on dynamic translate() to fade in slides.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand right, you want both translate and opacity to be included in an animation use this :

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  animation-name: fromleft;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}

@keyframes fromleft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```