Web animation API composite accumulate
I'm trying to understand if it's possible to accumulate animations with the Web API animation and I can't seem to figure it out.
//move element very fast to 100,100 with no duration
el.animate([{transform: 'translate(100px, 100px)'}], {duration: 0, fill: 'forwards'});

//add another movement after that with duration
el.animate([{transform: 'translateX(200px)'}], {duration: 0, fill: 'forwards', composite: 'accumulate'});

Everything happens properly, the box moves to 100,100 then the animation starts. The problem is, at the end of the animation, the boxes moves up like it has suddenly lost the Y transform. It is possible to keep the Y transform at the end? I thought fill: 'forwards' + composite : 'accumulate' would do that ...
Note: once in a while, it does behave properly so I'm not sure what's going on. The expected behavior is

Move box to 100,100
Then apply a relative transform, meaning the box would end up at 300,100



const el = document.querySelector('.box');

el.animate([{transform: 'translate(100px, 100px)'}], {duration: 0, fill: 'forwards'});

el.animate([{transform: 'translateX(200px)'}], {duration: 2000, fill: 'forwards', composite: 'accumulate'});
.container{
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box{
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: brown;
 }
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">  
  </div>
</div>



JsFiddle

I don't think composite: 'accumulate' applies globally, I would expect it to only combine the styles within a single set of keyframes. Are you sure you need two completely separate animations on the same element?

Also, I don't think it's the problem, but you're missing a closing bracket on the translate(100px, 100px

Good catch, edited but it behaves the same. What do you mean by 'accumulate' doesn't apply globally? What would be the point of accumulate then ?

As far as I remember composite option is not that smart, it compiles different types of transforms into one, but much more like string concatenation. This behavior can change in the future based on different vendors.
For the time being, you can use DOMMatrix to perform the operations you want prior to animating the element. This gives you quiet a bit of control on how you would want 'composite' to behave.
In the example I am using a dom manipulation library but you can easily get the promise from native Element.animate via finished prop. The rest is getting the current transformation matrix via getComputedStyle and using that to accumulate transformations via DOMMatrix.prototype. In this example, I am using DOMMAtrix.prototype.translateSelf.

A word of note, using getComputedStyle sparingly in your scripts, you
usually do this via polling/throttling the function that makes the
call to it. Another option is to set a property or Symbol on the element that keeps track of the current DOMMatrix so you do not have to call getComputedStyle.



(async () => {
 const el = document.querySelector('.box');
 await ch(el).animate([{transform: 'translate(100px, 100px)'}], {duration: 2000, fill: 'forwards'}).promiseAnimate();
 const currMatrix = new DOMMatrix(getComputedStyle(el).transform);
 ch.animate([{transform: currMatrix.translateSelf(200)}], {duration: 2000, fill: 'forwards'})
})()
.container{
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box{
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: brown;
 }
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cahir@0.0.6/dist/cahir.0.0.6.evergreen.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cahir@0.0.6/collections/DOM/ch.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">  
  </div>
</div>




Thanks, I was in fact already getting/setting the matrix and I thought for a while that 'accumulate' was actually doing that and not just joining strings... disappointed by this feature.

I think in order to achieve that, you would need to remove the transform and set your animate function with left and top properties.
As I clearly understand from your post and have tested it a bit, you wanted your current box to remain in the last position where the second animations ends. The transform function I think it is a bit tricky though as it is somehow resetting the Y axis position and it pushes your box to the top of the container for some reason.
I believe it is better to work both of your animations with the aforementioned properties.
I am attaching you a reproducible example which for me the animations are working as expected from what you described.
I hope that can help you with what you seek.


const el = document.querySelector('.box');
el.animate([{left: '100px', top:'0'}], {duration: 0, fill: 'both'});

el.animate([{left: '200px', top: '100px'}], {duration: 2000, fill: 'both', composite: 'accumulate'});
.container{
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box{
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: brown;
 }
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">  
  </div>
</div>




Yea it kind of does what I want but it wasn't really about moving the box but more be able to "merge" transforms via animate. It was more of a proof of concept to test if 'accumulate' does merge, or accumulates transforms but I guess it's not what it was made for.

I think the transforms in-built function is better for using it with keyframes in my opinion. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110205/combine-css-animation-with-transform it is doing what you want to achieve through the CSS animation keyframes.

Well, I was trying to check if I should move away from CSS animation and use the new "replacement" Web API animation which does support keyframes. My understanding now is I have to calculate and update the keyframes, which is kind of counter productive vs calculating and applying a transform directly in the code...

yep, I have been reading that you can reduce drastically the loading time with Web API animation instead of doing it with CSS keyframes.
